# PHP 5.4.4 plugin-system without php extensions

Tags: php, plugins, fread

I want to create a plugin-system that does not need php extensions like 'classkit' or 'curl' and changing the 'php.ini', so that it can run on the very most web-servers. The problem is that I have a constant-running script with `set_time_limit(0)` and I want to reload my plugins without closing the script.

That would be very easy with fread and exec, BUT php version 5.4.4 have a very stupid behavior: it does exec things between `<?php` and `?>`, so that I can not read the file.

My question is how I can make a plugin-system nevertheless with php version 5.4.4?

Thanks for replying.